# Insert new row just below the clicked row with the use of rowIndex

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below is a code i wrote to do the following things

- each table row contains a '+' button
- when click on the button the code should find the row index of the clicked row
- then a new row should add to the cilcked row's (rowindex+1) position. ie, just below the clicked row.

But now the problems arise is that

- the onclick function inside button is not working , if i write it inside  then it will work
- the onclick of button in 'cell3' is not working

As i am a beginner in php and very beginner in javascript, can anyone please help me with detailed explanation

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var rowno=x.rowIndex;
alert(rowno);

var row = table.insertRow(rowno+1);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text"s name="txt1">';
cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="txt2">';
cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="button" name="btn" value="+" onclick="myFunction(this)">';

}
</script>
```

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">

<tr>
<td>Row1 cell1</td>
<td>Row1 cell2</td>
<td><button onclick="myFunction(this)">+</button></td>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td>Row1 cell1</td>
<td>Row1 cell2</td>
<td><button onclick="myFunction(this)">+</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Row1 cell1</td>
<td>Row1 cell2</td>
<td><button onclick="myFunction(this)">+</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the button to your function and trying to find its rowIndex which is not possible. You need to find the rowIndex of the button's parent row. I have modified the javascript code to select it. This should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(x) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var rowno = x.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; //this selects the button's parent row        
        alert(rowno);
        var row = table.insertRow(rowno + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text"s name="txt1">';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="txt2">';
        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="button" name="btn" value="+" onclick="myFunction(this)">';

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Aw..Thanks a lot @dennisjsk this is what i exactly wanted..!! :D